# Watching changes in children recursively with DynamicData

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, dynamic-data

I'm creating a fully generic file explorer for AvaloniaUI. It has a view that shows a folder tree that you can navigate by expanding each directory.

**My goal is to make this view flexible enough to support selecting multiple items from multiple nodes.**

The problem? The tree is dynamic. Not only are the children lazily loaded, but also the user can potentially create new items (like folders), and select them.

- I currently have a `IFileItem` interface to represent the items in the file structure. I have `Folder` and `File` currently.
- Folders can have other entries (folders + files), of course.
- Both File and Folder are ViewModels (even though I'm not adding the ViewModel suffix )

```
interface IFileItem
{
    string Path { get; }
}

class Folder : IFileItem
{
     ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IFileEntry> { get; }
     ...
}

class File : IFileItem
{
     ...
}
```

To support the selection feature, my plan is to add a property `ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IFileItem> SelectedItems`:

```
class Folder : IFileEntry
{
     ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IFileItem> Children { get; }
     bool IsSelected { get; set; } 
     ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IFileItem> SelectedItems { get; }
     
     ...
}
```

The `SelectedItems` property **should hold a list of whatever it's selected in a given branch**, this is, the given node + the children.
This approach could be useful, *and might be what I need, but I'm not sure how well is this solution for supporting scenarios like **single folder picking**.*

**Now the question: How do we define the `SelectedItems` property???**

It should watch change of this.IsSelected AND Children.IsSelected RECURSIVELY. Now that's hard.
I'm not familiarized with any use case like this in DynamicData, but I think it should be handled. For now, I'm completely stuck.

I hope someone could come with a nice solution in a purely DD way :)

Comment: ObservableCollection generally and similar like List....

Comment: Can you give us more context as to what both collections hold and can you give sample data in C# format?

Comment: @Enigmativity I've updated the question to be more concise. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's partially implemented solution. It's a pain and it's got a fair bit of work to be fully functional, but this works for demonstrating how to maintain the `SelectedItems` collection at all of the levels.

Start with the basic interface and abstract class:

```
public interface IFileItem
{
    string Path { get; }
    bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    event Action<bool> Selected;
}

public abstract class FileItemBase : IFileItem
{
    public FileItemBase(string path) => this.Path = path;
    public virtual string Path { get; }

    private bool _isSelected = false;

    public virtual bool IsSelected
    {
        get => _isSelected;
        set
        {
            _isSelected = value;
            this?.Selected(value);
        }
    }
    
    public event Action<bool> Selected;
}
```

I then implemented `File`:

```
public class File : FileItemBase
{
    public File(string path) : base(path) { }
}
```

And then `Folder`:

```
public class Folder : FileItemBase
{
    public Folder(string path) : base(path)
    {
        _children = new ObservableCollection<IFileItem>();
        this.Children = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IFileItem>(_children);
        _selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<IFileItem>();
        this.SelectedItems = new ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IFileItem>(_selectedItems);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<IFileItem> _children;
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IFileItem> Children { get; }

    private ObservableCollection<IFileItem> _selectedItems = new ObservableCollection<IFileItem>();
    public ReadOnlyObservableCollection<IFileItem> SelectedItems { get; }

    private IEnumerable<IFileItem> Recurse()
    {
        foreach (var _child in _children)
        {
            yield return _child;
            if (_child is Folder folder)
            {
                foreach (var x in folder.Recurse())
                {
                    yield return x;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void Add(IFileItem fileItem)
    {
        _children.Add(fileItem);
        if (fileItem.IsSelected)
        {
            _selectedItems.Add(fileItem);
        }
        fileItem.Selected += isSelected =>
        {
            if (isSelected)
            {
                _selectedItems.Add(fileItem);
            }
            else
            {
                _selectedItems.Remove(fileItem);
            }
        };
        if (fileItem is Folder folder)
        {
            (folder.SelectedItems as System.Collections.Specialized.INotifyCollectionChanged).CollectionChanged += (s, e) =>
            {
                switch (e.Action)
                {
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add:
                        foreach (var item in e.NewItems.OfType<IFileItem>())
                            if (item.IsSelected)
                                _selectedItems.Add(item);
                        break;
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Move:
                        break;
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove:
                        foreach (var item in e.OldItems.OfType<IFileItem>())
                                _selectedItems.Remove(item);
                        break;
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace:
                        break;
                    case System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset:
                        var removes = this.SelectedItems.Except(this.Recurse().Where(x => x.IsSelected)).ToList();
                        foreach (var remove in removes)
                            _selectedItems.Remove(remove);
                        break;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Now my test was done in LINQPad:

```
void Main()
{
    var f1 = new Folder("X");
    var f2 = new Folder("XY");
    var f3 = new Folder("XZ");
    var f4 = new File("Xa");
    var f5 = new File("XYa");
    var f6 = new File("XYb");
    var f7 = new File("XZa");
    
    f1.Add(f2);
    f1.Add(f3);
    
    f1.Add(f4);
    f2.Add(f5);
    f2.Add(f6);
    f3.Add(f7);

    f1.SelectedItems.Dump();

    f7.IsSelected = true;

    f1.SelectedItems.Dump();

    f7.IsSelected = false;

    f1.SelectedItems.Dump();
}
```

So even though `f7` is nested below `f3` and `f3` is below `f1` it still appears and disappears in `f1`'s collection.

[image: results]

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I've seen you followed the "classic path". Is there any reason why you didn't use anything reactive? In the OP I wanted to use DynamicData because normally this kind of scenarios are covered in a very concise and elegant way. One of the things I don't like about this approach is having to deal with event handlers and their susbscriptions. I'd like to avoid them at all cost :)

Comment: @SuperJMN - I generally do too try to avoid them. I'll have a rethink.